# Reverse Order of Array Elements with Foreach Loop using Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I have a Score-Table with different ratings, strings and radio-buttons.

Now I want to loop through these. Normally I would go about solving it like this:

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Comment</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($scores as $score)

    <tr>
        <td>{{$score->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$score->ratingradio}}</td>
        <td>{{$score->ratingtext}}</td>
    </tr>

    @endforeach
</table>
```

But I don't only want the order to be reversed, but I also want the array to be sliced, so that it just outputs the last 20 Elements of the array.

I attempted solving it like this in my Controller:

```
$scores = Score::where('unit_id', $id)->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(3))->get();


// Save all ratingtexts in an array
$comments = $scores->lists('ratingtext');
$commenttype = $scores->lists('ratingradio');
// Get the last 20 Elements of the Array
$comments = array_slice($comments, -20, 20, true);
// Reverse the array, to have the latest element first displayed
$comments = array_reverse($comments, true);
```

And then looping through the $comments. But I don't only want to display the comment, I also want to be able to display all Information regarding this Element. So preferably like the above method with eloquent, where I output $score->ratingtext, $score->ratingradio, $score-id, and whatever I want.

I tried just using

```
 @foreach(array_reverse($scores) as $score)
```

Which obviously didn't work, because $scores is an object and it was expecting an array. How am I going to reverse loop through every score of my Scores Table?

Comment: Why don't you simply set `orderBy` and `limit` to fetch only 20 rows?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Retrieving the last 20 items is quite easy.

```
$scores = Score::where('unit_id', $id)
    ->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(3))
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->take(20)
    ->get();

$scores = $scores->reverse();
```

Done.

Just tell it to pull out the first 20 items that match your query, with a reversed order and then reverse the collection to get the proper order.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? The above will do exactly what it's supposed to do.

Comment: The problem with the above is the array key in the collection does not change and if passed using JSON, it reverts.

Comment: I'm not following @RazorMureithi, what key?

Comment: Let me try to explain what I remember the $scores variable currently has the right order if you lets say return with JSON i.e. return response()->json(['date'=>$scores]) it will revert the order.
this is because the collection index did not change/

Answer (score 20):

You can as well easily do `@foreach($scores->reverse() as $score)`

Answer (score 11):

You can use:

```
array_reverse($scores->toArray());
```

or Eloquent\Collection methods to keep the Model object

```
$scores->reverse();
```

Take a look at the [Eloquent\Collection API](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html).

Comment: To clear it up, `$scores = Score::where('unit_id', $id)->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(3))->get()->reverse()->take(20)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

There are even easyest way:

```
$scores = Score::where('unit_id', $id)
    ->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(3))
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
    ->take(20)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score -2):

Looking through the API, it seems you can use `take()` to make this very simple.  It behaves a little differently when running on query builder vs collection, so you'd want to get your collection first.

`$scores = Score::where('unit_id', $id)->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(3))->get()->take(-20);`